# pylint reports _ as not callable

Tags: python, pylint

### Problem

I have imported ugettext_lazy as _ but pylint complains that _ is not callable. Is there a way to ignore this error message?

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
...
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Name"))
```

### Answer

It seems I've found half of answer. There is a way to ignore certain messages.

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=E1102[,<msg id>]+
```

to get list of messages and ids:

```
shell> pylint --list-msgs
```

Why its only half of solution? Well no it does not report situations like this:

```
asdf = 5
asdf()
```

Maybe there is a way to specify error cause, but thats for another day :|.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why not use something slightly less magic than `_`?

Comment: Well to use _ is convention thingie, and django docs shows to use _. Even wiki shows _ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext .

Comment: It's not just a Django convention, it's a Python convension. See the [`gettext.gettext`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.gettext) docs: "This function is usually aliased as _() in the local namespace"

Comment: It's not just a Python convention, it's a gettext convention, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Mark-Keywords

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the message in your pylintrc file to avoid a false-positive is definitly not a solution as it will totally deactivate this check.

Taking a look at django's source code, it seems like pylint doesn't like the `lazy()` stuff.
Django people should probably read http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/78354 and start a django specific plugin, which could easily fix such problems.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in your pylintrc file

```
[VARIABLES]
additional-builtins=_
```

This will add the underscore symbol to a list of additional names supposed to be defined in builtins and pylint will not complain about it.

Answer (score 1):

`pylint --additional-builtins=_ ...` will get the job done in most scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

_ refers to the last outputed value

so, that could probably be the error cause

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> print _
2
>>> _("foo")
 TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: This is true in a Python REPL, but that is not the case for the OP.